# .htaccess question : Can I strip out a leading question mark?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a page that already has the $_GET array initialized, and when a page redirects there (with an oAuth token) it appends the `?token=36264747` to the end.

Is there a way to write an .htaccess file for an Apache server that would either strip that question mark or (better) replace it with an ampersand?

Comment: I don’t quite get it. Can you give an example?

Comment: Yes, this is for a Facebook application. It is set up so that when you access apps.facebook.com/myapp, that actually refers to www.myserver.com/myapp?controller=start. When this application goes through oAuth with twitter, it's referred back to apps.facebook/myapp?token=1520682608236, which is actually myserver.com/myapp?controller=start?token=1520682608236, which is an illegal URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `qsappend` or `QSA` (query string append) flag for RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^foo(.*)bar$ index.php?token=$1 [QSA]
```

will append `token=$1` to the query string (the $_GET part), using `?` or `&` as appropriate.

Comment: aah! Don't you just love it when it's 5:34 AM and SO's a lifesaver?